# recursive function running infinitely even while calling return

Tags: python, recursion

I created a basic python function to recursively print Fibonacci's numbers. However, after printing all the numbers it continues printing 0 infinitely

I've tried to use the return keyword and putting an if statement before to check if the variable is bigger than it should be but it still hasn't worked

```py
class RecFibonnacci:

    def recFib(self, firstTerm, secondTerm):
        Fterm = firstTerm
        Sterm = secondTerm

        if Fterm <= 1000:
            print(Fterm)
            tempStrg = Fterm
            Sterm += Fterm
            Fterm = tempStrg
            self.recFib(Fterm, Sterm)
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    recFibonacci = RecFibonnacci()
    recFibonacci.recFib(0, 1)
```

it should print all the Fibonacci numbers from 1-987. it prints them but afterwards, it prints 0 forever

Comment: You have no base case, you always call recFib(0,1)

Comment: the first term never gets incremented

Comment: Like I mentioned before, I've tried to put this before "if Fterm > 1000: return"  but it hasn't worked

Comment: I think you are not clear on how arguments are passed to functions.  Read up on pass by value vs pass by reference.  All the acrobatics you are doing with Fterm and Sterm make no sense.

Comment: search a basic fibonacci function in python and implement it as such before passing it to a class method.

Comment: @chepner I meant "die" in the loving sense of the word.

Comment: @MK. maybe. I may have upvoted him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is fine, except one small mistake that is --

> your variable Fterm is first(previous term) value and Sterm is second(first+second) and you were calling the function *self.recFib(Fterm, Sterm)* with this;

but what was happening is while calling recursively the variable Fterm was taking its old value, not the updated one! since it was failing to exceed 1000, apparently. 
therefore you can do two things out there --

**modification 1**

```
    Fterm = firstTerm
    Sterm = secondTerm

    if Fterm<= 1000:            
        print(Fterm)
        #updating first variable, and second as well (first+second)
        self.recFib(Sterm, Sterm+Fterm)
    return
```

**modification 2**

```
if Fterm <= 1000:           
   print(Fterm)
   tempStrg = Fterm
   Sterm += Fterm
   Fterm = tempStrg
   # passing second as first, and first as second
   self.recFib(Sterm, Fterm)
return
```

Answer (score 2):

While other answers might produce working code you need to understand that what you are trying to do is equivalent to

```
def recFib(self, firstTerm, secondTerm):
    if firstTerm <= 1000:
        print(firstTerm)
        self.recFib(secondTerm, firstTerm + secondTerm)
    return
```

Comment: Dang that's really simplified code, thanks hahah. Turns out I had just messed up a part of my code and I had another function that was being called and displaying the actual results instead of the recursive which was just printing 0. Thank you so much

Comment: No, like others pointed out, your code was incorrect, because you confused yourself by creating 3 unneeded temporary variables.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is a good code, except one small mistake.
You should replace the line

```
tempStrg = Fterm
```

with the line

```
tempStrg = Sterm
```

Comment: What part? If it is about the print then I was wrong and it was good, I edited the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think `tempStrg = Fterm` should be changed to `tempStrg = Sterm`. That's because if you assign `Fterm` to `tempStrg`, `Fterm` stays at 0. That's because the first term `Fterm` never gets incremented. Here's why: `tempStrg = Fterm` makes that 0. then if you change `Fterm` to that it still is zero. This is why it always outputs 0 forever. This is a small mistake in your code.